# Undesired behaviour in MergeSort function

Tags: c, sorting, merge, mergesort

I'm new to programming,I'm trying to implement a merge sort function into my program, but it's not working correctly. I went over and over the code but I can't find the problem.

If for example the user input for a 6 element array is : `3 2 4 1 6 7`

The output is: `1 3 2 4 32708 32708`

Can someone help me? Also, if anyone have any advice for improving my coding style would be much appreciated.Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int *a, n;

    a = malloc(100 * sizeof(int)); // dynamically allocating memory for original array

    if (a == NULL)
        return 1;

    printf("Enter n of elements in the array:");

    scanf("%i", &n); // n of elements the in array

    printf("Enter elements:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%i", &a[i]); // prompt user for input elements
    }

    int f, l, m, n1, n2; // declaring variables

    f = 0;               // first element
    l = n - 1;           // last element
    m = (f + l) / 2;     // mid point
    n1 = m + 1 - f;      // n elements l1
    n2 = l - m;          // n elements l2

    int l1[n1];          // temp array 1
    int l2[n2];          // temp array2

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        l1[i] = a[i];    // copy elements into temp l1
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        l2[j] = a[m + 1 + j]; // copy elements into temp l2
    }

    int i, j, k; // variable for arrays index

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = 0;

    //sorting and copying elements in original array

    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (l1[i] <= l2[j]) { // if element l1 smaller or equal to l2 element
            a[k] = l1[i];     // copy element l1 into original array
            i++;              // increment l1
        } else {              // if element l1 bigger than l2
            a[k] = l2[j];     // copy element l2 into original array
            j++;              // increment l2
        }
        k++; // increment original array
    }

    // copy remaining elements (if any)
    while (i < n1) {
        a[k] = l1[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < n2) {
        a[k] = l2[i];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    printf("Your sorted array:\n");

    for (int d = 0; d < n; d++) {
        printf("%i ", a[d]); // print sorted array
    }

    printf("\n");

    free(a); // freeing original array
}
```

Comment: The I/O work should be in a separate function from the merge sort algorithm.  The I/O can stay in `main()`, but you need a separate `mergesort()` function to sort the array.  For 100 elements, there's really no need to use `malloc()` — just declare the array locally in `main()`.  If the array size reaches a megabyte or so, then you stop using a local array, but until then, there's no need to go for dynamic allocation just on account of size.  You should check that the user doesn't try to add 200 numbers to your 100 element array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge recursively. You wrote only the merge part and not the recursive sort function.

More info: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r) 
{ 
    int i, j, k; 
    int n1 = m - l + 1; 
    int n2 = r - m; 
  
    /* create temp arrays */
    int L[n1], R[n2]; 
  
    /* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) 
        L[i] = arr[l + i]; 
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) 
        R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j]; 
  
    /* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
    i = 0; // Initial index of first subarray 
    j = 0; // Initial index of second subarray 
    k = l; // Initial index of merged subarray 
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) { 
        if (L[i] <= R[j]) { 
            arr[k] = L[i]; 
            i++; 
        } else { 
            arr[k] = R[j]; 
            j++; 
        } 
        k++; 
    } 
  
    /* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there are any */
    while (i < n1) { 
        arr[k] = L[i]; 
        i++; 
        k++; 
    } 
  
    /* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there are any */
    while (j < n2) { 
        arr[k] = R[j]; 
        j++; 
        k++; 
    } 
} 

void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r) 
{ 
    if (l < r) { 
        // Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for 
        // large l and h 
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2; 
  
        // Sort first and second halves 
        mergeSort(arr, l, m); 
        mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r); 
  
        merge(arr, l, m, r); 
    } 
}

int main(void)
{
    int *a, n;

    printf("Enter n of elements in the array:");
    scanf("%i", &n); //n of elements the in array

    a = malloc(n * sizeof(int)); //dynamically allocating memory for original array
    if (a == NULL)
        return 1;

    printf("Enter elements:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%i", &a[i]); //prompt user for input elements
    }
    
    mergeSort(a, 0, n - 1);
    
    printf("Your sorted array:\n");

    for (int d = 0; d < n; d++) {
        printf("%i ", a[d]); //print sorted array
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(a); //freeing original array
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see,thanks Jacob.Is there a sorting function that is not done recursively?Just to have a clearer idea of the actual coding "under the hood" so to speak.

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the array allocation and simplify the initial call to `mergeSort()`.